# How do we compile and run a program in the CS50 IDE?

Tags: c++, ide, cs50

Basically, I am a starter in programming. I do not understand how do I compile and run the program below on Harvard's [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, CS50";
}
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjiUU.png)

Comment: For compiling C++, you use g++. `g++ file.cpp -o output -Wall`

Comment: Did you learn "`using namespace std;` from the CS50 class?  If so, you should demand your money back (also, because they didn't provide you instructions or tools to build the program and execute it).  Remove the `namespace` statement and use `std::cout` or use `using std::cout;`

Comment: Not sure if you follow the course materials, but it is extensively explained in the notes. https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/notes/1/

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64015744/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start typing in the terminal. Follow each `command` you type with the [Enter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) key.

Use the command `ls` to list all the files in your directory. One of those files should be the code you just wrote and saved.
It's not a requirement, but it will make it easier to have the filename end in '.cpp'. If your file does not have that, you can save the file again and add '.cpp' to the filename.

Assuming that your filename is "hello.cpp", use the command `g++ hello.cpp` to compile your code. This will create another file called `a.out`.

You can now run your code with the command `./a.out`. After doing this you should see that "Hello, CS50" has been printed onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1: save your file name with .cpp extension. If your file does not have that, you can save the file again and add '.cpp' to the filename.

2: Consider that your filename is "hello.cpp", use the command make hello to compile your code. This will create another file called hello.

3: Now you can write your code with the commond ./hello. After doing this you should see the Output.